# Arduino - Serial1 not available

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

im learning coding with arduino and c#. my program send by bluetooth commands to do for platform with stepper motors ( simple list of moves). 
Step first - After recive informations, prepare them to use (format !,.(...)@ (eg. !1,100.3,90.@ mean move forward(1) for 100 ms, move left(3) 90 ms. ! -start of stream  @ - end of stream)
Step two - execute moves 
Step three - if no more, proceed loop till next information come to Serial1 (which mean start step first.
And it even works, but after first recived string my Serial1.available() returns false ;/
i have no idea why? is he busy or what? i can't recive second string of commands

```
#define a1 4  //stepper motor connection
#define a2 3
#define b1 5
#define b2 6
int licznikRuch = 0; // counter for tabMove
int licznikCzas = 0;// counter for tabTime
 int kolejka = 0;
bool CiagRuch = false;
bool CiagCzas = false; // 
bool Zakonczono = false; // 
int SubPoczatek, SubKoniec; // substring start / substring end
bool Wykonaj = false;
String tabMove[100];
String tabTime[100];
String inputString = "";

String StringCzas = "";
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial1.begin(9600); //
 Serial2.begin(9600);
 inputString.reserve(200);
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  tabMove[i] = "";
  tabTime[i] = "";
 }
 pinMode(19, OUTPUT);pinMode(17,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(51,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(a1, OUTPUT); pinMode(a2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(b1, OUTPUT);  pinMode(b2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(a1,LOW);  digitalWrite(a2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(b1,LOW);  digitalWrite(b2,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
if(Zakonczono){  // operacje na wczytanym ciagu. wydobycie rozkazow i czasu
    Serial.println(inputString);    
    for(int i = 0; i < inputString.length();i++){
      if(inputString[i] == '!'){
        for(int l =0;l<100;l++){
          Wykonaj = false;
          tabTime[l] = "";
          tabMove[l] = "";
          licznikCzas = 0;
          licznikRuch = 0;
          }
        }
        if(inputString[i] == '@'){
          Wykonaj = true;
          }     
      if(inputString[i] == '.'){
        SubKoniec = i;
        tabTime[licznikCzas++] = inputString.substring(SubPoczatek+1,SubKoniec);
        CiagCzas = false; 
        StringCzas = "";               
        }
      if(inputString[i] == ','){
        tabMove[licznikRuch++] = inputString[i-1];
        CiagCzas = true;
        SubPoczatek = i;
        }         
      }
      for(int i = 0; i< licznikCzas;i++)
      Serial.println(i+"Ruch"+tabMove[i]+"Czas:"+tabTime[i]);    
    Zakonczono = false;
    inputString= "";
  }      
     while(Wykonaj) // if you cut off whole this loop Serial1 is still available and recive commands
      {    
        if(tabMove[kolejka] == "1")    // move forward     
        {          
        digitalWrite(a1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(a2,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(b1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(b2,HIGH);       
        delay(tabTime[kolejka].c_str());
         Serial.print("1");
        digitalWrite(a1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(a2,LOW);
        digitalWrite(b1,LOW);
        digitalWrite(b2,LOW); 
          kolejka++;
                // Serial.print(kolejka);
          }
          if(tabMove[kolejka] == "2"){ // left
            digitalWrite(a1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(a2,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(b1,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(b2,LOW);
            delay(tabTime[kolejka].c_str());
            Serial.print("2");
            digitalWrite(a1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(a2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b2,LOW);
            kolejka++;
            }
             if(tabMove[kolejka] == "3"){ // right
            digitalWrite(a1,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(a2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b2,HIGH);
            delay(tabTime[kolejka].c_str());
            Serial.print("3");
            digitalWrite(a1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(a2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b2,LOW);
            kolejka++;
            }
            if(tabMove[kolejka] == "4"){ // back
            digitalWrite(a1,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(a2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b1,HIGH);
            digitalWrite(b2,LOW);
            delay(tabTime[kolejka].c_str());
            Serial.print("3");
            digitalWrite(a1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(a2,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b1,LOW);
            digitalWrite(b2,LOW);
            kolejka++;
            }
            if(tabMove[kolejka] == ""){
              Wykonaj = false; 
              if(!Serial1.available())                         
              Serial.print("Serial1 not avaliable ;(");     // ???                    
              break;
              }              
       }

}

void serialEvent1(){
     char Znak = "_";
   //  char PoprzedniZnak = Znak; 
  while(Serial1.available()){
    // Serial.write(Znak);  
     Znak = (char)Serial1.read();    
     inputString+= Znak;   
     if(Znak == '\n')
     Zakonczono = true; 
     kolejka = 0;
    }

  }
```

Comment: my mistake, tag Serial and arduino should be enough but i cant use it yet

Answer (score -2):

Alright, first of all, let's get out of the way the silly things:

1. Have your tried to connect/reconnect the usb from your pc to arduino?
2. Have you tried to restart your pc and unplug the usb?
3. Have you checked that you have NO wire attached to pin 0 (RX) pin once you upload the code? This is a very common mistake, if it's the case take out the wire from pin 0 before you upload, then upload and put in the wire again after the upload is FULLY complete (you will get the white writings when it is)
4. Make sure that your pc drives are up to date, and you can see the serial in both your periferials, AND the IDE and it's connected properly

Ok now that this is out the way, a few suggestions:

1. Write the error number in the post, Serial.available is false, does not mean anything, should Serial.available = true and then something happens and you trigger the condition of Serial.available false?
2. Your code is a mess (no offense), make sure you make it a little nicer if you want others to give it a shot!

**Now to your problem:**

I don't know wheter you mean that your code is bad or it's the serial as serial port that is going ape.

**So here is 2 solutions**

For the code:

What you wrote here will not work and that's why the serial is **not available**:

```
void serialEvent1(){
     char Znak = "_";
   //  char PoprzedniZnak = Znak; 
  while(Serial1.available()){  //What kind of condition is this?
    // Serial.write(Znak);  
     Znak = (char)Serial1.read(); //This does not work! Why using char and convert when
//You can use a string!

     inputString+= Znak;   
     if(Znak == '\n')
     Zakonczono = true; 
     kolejka = 0;
    }

  }
```

It should be this:

```
void serialEvent1(){
     String Znak = "_";

  while(Serial1.available() == 0){
    // Serial.write(Znak);  
     Znak = Serial1.readString();    
     inputString+= Znak;   
     if(Znak == '\n')  //This is quite weird if a char or a String == 
//enter(button)?

     Zakonczono = true; 
     kolejka = 0;
    }

  }
```

0 if you want it to start on an input into the serial, plus I would SERIOUSLY recommended that you do not use a while loop if this is a choice program, unless you encompass all the choices in the while loop and then you have another while loop that takes care of other choices

But said that let's go over the second solution:

Serial as in hardware:

You have to write me the error number you are getting otherwise I cannot help you, check my steps above and make sure that you are not making one of those mistakes, if you are not please write your error number in the post.

Hope it helped!
And that I wasn't too harsh ;)